# JavaScript Replacing Text With HTML Not Working?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to get my website to find certain text and replace it with an `<img>` tag using this code...

```
function Emote() {
    var stringg = document.getElementsByClassName("Post").innerHTML;
    var resolutionn = stringg.replace("xD", "<img src='Icons/xD.gif' width='100px' height='100px' />")
    document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = resolutionn;
}
Emote();
```

When I debug with Firebug it outputs this...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return-value of `document.getElementsByClassName("Post").innerHTML` is `undefined`.

That because `document.getElementsByClassName` is retouring an array, not a single Element.

Use `document.getElementsByClassName("Post")[0].innerHTML` to access the first:

```
<script>
    function Emote() {
        var stringg = document.getElementsByClassName("Post")[0].innerHTML;
        var resolutionn = stringg.replace("xD", "<img src='Icons/xD.gif' width='100px' height='100px' />")
        document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = resolutionn;
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", Emote);
    // or window.onload = Emote();
</script>
```

Comment: I thought it would work but it now gives me this output...
https://imgur.com/H6TWCtE

Comment: so this tells you that, there was no Element with this className found in your document. Consider it's case-sensitive, maybe you use "post" not "Post" ?

Comment: Nope, my html is p class="Post", my CSS works with .Post{} so I don't understand why this isn't working o.o.

Comment: Umm, well it's a whole web-page so, view-source:http://insanewolfhd.byethost17.com/

Comment: Oh. I guess you are executing the Script before the HTML? So it will not be there in the moment the script executes. Use window.onload (updated my ansewer)

Comment: Ooooohhhhh okay, now I just need to understand how to manipulate the array thing and I can make it select all of the "xD"s and that'd be good, so thank you :D. It worked!

Comment: var array = document.getElementsByClassName("Post"); for(let i=0; i<array.length; ++i) {array[i]/*this is your element*/}

Comment: That worked awesome, thank you :D :). I wish I could give rep but +1 I guess lol.

Comment: you could go on my profile.. and upvote other usefull answers of me, huhu :P - but nvm it's free! you are welcome

Answer (score 3):

The function `getElementsByClassName` returns an **array** of elements, rather than a single element. Arrays do not have the property `innerHTML`, thus such will be undefined.

If you want to apply this function to the first element matching the class, use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Post")[0].innerHTML
```

instead.

Comment: this is not the complete solution guys